# Adding request-id (or operation-id) to HTTPS request made by a web hook event suscription of an azure event grid topic

Tags: azure, .net-core, webhooks, telemetry, azure-eventgrid

I have 2 Web APIs in .NET Core which communicate between themselves sending events to an azure event grid topic. This event grid topic has 2 web hooks event subscriptions (one for each API) that do a HTTPS request to the other API whenever a event is send to the topic.

Also I have an Application Insight for logging and monitoring both APIs. I want to be able to relate the logs of both APIs. I know that this is done out of the box for HTTP requests between both APIs using a `Request-Id` header. Is it possible to add such thing in the web hooks?

Or if not, is it possible to implement a custom middleware or filter to handle this?

Comment: The AEG distributes an event message payload based on the EventGridSchema (default), CloudEventV01Schema and CustomEventSchema. These schemas have a custom data property where can be passed your data to the subscriber. Currently the AEG doesn't have a support for mapping some properties to the webhook headers. However, it can be done using the azure function (EventGridTrigger) as your integrator (mediator) to your webhook endpoint.

Comment: Hi thanks you for your answer. I have used a function for other things, but the cold start time of the functions is too much for what I'm doing in here.